# How to prevent a background image flickering on change

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm applying a repeated background image from a canvas to a div via javascript like this:

```
var img_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

img_canvas.width = 16;

img_canvas.height = 16;

img_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 16, 16);

var img = img_canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

document.querySelector('#div').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + img + ')';
```

I have to update it quite frequently. The problem is it flickers upon change, it doesn't appear to happen in Chrome but it's really bad in Firefox and Safari. Is it possible to stop this? I didn't think it would happen since it's a dataurl and therefore doesn't need to be downloaded.

**Solution:**

```
// create a new Image object
var img_tag = new Image();

// when preload is complete, apply the image to the div
img_tag.onload = function() {

    document.querySelector('#div').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + img + ')';
}

// setting 'src' actually starts the preload
img_tag.src = img;
```

Comment: Your solution works great. Consider adding it an answer :)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm having the same issue on Safari, even with the onload trick. Is this still working for you with the latest version of Safari? Chrome is fine.

Comment: I love this solution! I have 257 images at 1700 x 956 playing as a background image on my node-webkit app and it's freakin gorgeous. Node-webkit doesn't play a whole lot of movies by default; it is possible with a lot of hair pulling and with the web-chimera plugin. Thank you so much for showing me the way. This is after 4 hours of frustration. You gave me back my life.

Comment: @logidelic did you find a solution? I am also having the issue persist on FF and Safari as well.. Works on Chrome, Edge, IE 11, etc.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for that! Saved me hours of work.

Comment: Note that the image will still flicker if caching is disabled on your browser. I had developer console open with caching disabled and lost some time trying to figure out why this fix wasn't working for me because I didn't realize this.

Comment: I had this issue and i saw that the pain phase of the rendering pipeline spiked that solution is actually great! solved my perf options on Firefox (119) and Safari (17)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try to preload the image resource to the device storage by including the image in DOM like in the following HTML-Code. Maybe the error comes up because the image resource need to be loaded which takes some time (flickering).

```
<img src="imageToPreload.png" style="display:none;" alt="" />
```

You may prefer to use [sprites-images](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). By using sprites your application will need less HTTP-Requests to load all ressources into your page. Also add the following CSS styles if you are using `css animations`. It will prevent background flickering on mobile devices:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
```

Comment: Thank you, I managed to do it by loading it via an `Image` first. I edited in an example of this to my original question.

Comment: Was stuck on this for ages! Such an easy fix too. I wish i could use a sprite image but my images are way too big! Thanks again ++

Comment: I just needed the preload to fix my flicker - the CSS `visibility` rules weren't needed.

Comment: @Air, while running CSS3 Animations on mobile devices, you will need to add `backface-visibility` to some elements to prevent flickering. But thats an other case to a "resource preloader".

Answer (score 9):

Preload your image like this, no need to include a `<img>` with `display: none`

```
<link rel="preload" href="/images/bg-min.png" as="image">
```

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this css to your background element:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
```

It should help with flickering..

You can also "force" hardware acceleration by adding this to your background element:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Another option is to use image instead of DIV and change only the image url.

Comment: Didn't seem to stop it unfortunately. I managed to stop it completely by preloading it to an Image as suggested. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I just needed the preload to fix my flicker - the CSS `visibility` rules weren't needed.

Comment: Had flickering on iphone X and your solution of forcing hardware acceleration on the div fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a bit, tried preloading, appending the image to the document, etc.

In the end, I **resaved the JPEG without the "Progressive"** option.

That fixed the rolling flicker when the img src was swapped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing `height: 1080px;` (background height) to `height: fit-content;`

Answer (score 0):

I think that preloading all the images is essential in any case. What I found is that the way the browsers behave while changing the background image dynamically is different from one another. In Firefox for example it flickers when the change is frequent however in Chrome and Safari it doesn't.

The best solution I came up with so far is drawing the image inside a child `canvas` that fills the space of the whole parent `div`.

In all cases, the images you are using must be optimized as it affects the rendering performance.

Answer (score 0):

My javascript code that works now, looks like this

```
const pic = new Image();
const pic2 = new Image();

pic.src="../images/settings_referrals_anim.gif";
pic2.src="../images/settings_referrals_still.png";
```

I don't actually reference that code in the query, for example, i use

```
document.querySelector(".button_Settings_referrals").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  myDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/settings_referrals_anim.gif')";
```

But it seems to work. If I replace the long URL with const pic for example it doesn't work, and if I include the image object declaration and location at first time in the assignment, then the flickering stops.

Answer (score 0):

This does not address all of the specifics noted by the OP, but might be useful for others. Tested in Chrome 97, Firefox 96, Android 11, iOS 15.

I have a div that includes these CSS parameters...

```
#div_image {
    background-image: url( [Path to low-res image] );
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I have a corresponding class that looks like this...

```
.div_image_highres {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

The corresponding class has a pseudo-element defined as follows:

```
.div_image_highres::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    content: " ";
    
    background-image: url( [Path to highres image] );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-size: cover;
    
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

I have an img element that also points to the high-res image...

```
<img id="img_highres_preload" src=" [Path to high-res image ] ">
```

The img element has a corresponding style which allows the image to be displayed (ensuring that image file loads) but not seen...

```
#img_highres_preload {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}
```

Two notes: (1) I realize a lot of people use other methods of pre-loading (e.g., programmatically), but I have a personal preference for this method. (2) See the addendum about the reliability of the load event.

Last but not least, I have some Javascript (jQuery) that adds the "high-res" class to "div_image" once the high-res file is loaded...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#img_highres_preload").off().on("load", function() {
        $("#div_image").addClass("div_image_highres");
    });
});
```

This could easily be vanilla JS, but since I use jQuery throughout my code, I  like having a consistency.

---

**Here's a summary of what's happening...**

1. Presumably, the low-res image is loaded first and becomes the background image for the div. Even if that does not occur, everything will work as intended (i.e., the high-res image will be displayed).
2. When the high-res image loads into the img element (i.e., Javascript confirms that the high-res file is loaded), the "div_image_highres" class is applied to "div_image".
3. As result, the div switches to the high-res image without flashing. In my experience, if anything, it shifts a little to the left; but that often doesn't occur and, if it does, it's not inelegant.
4. And here's the primary reason I use this approach when required: In my application, there are multiple panels the user can navigate, which results in one panel sliding out of view and the new one into view. If I don't use a pseudo-element (as described above) for displaying a high-res image, the image flickers when its div is hidden and re-displayed. With the above-described technique, I can slide the div in and out of view without any flickering.

---

**Regarding the Load Event**

You can't depend on the load event firing. For instance, it typically does not fire when the browser has cached an image. So to make a long post even longer, here's the enhancement I have in my code to accommodate that reality...

I modify the document.ready event (shown above) to look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    positionOnPage(true);
    
    $("#img_highres_preload").off().on("load", function() {
        checkImage();
    });
});

checkImage = function() {
    var image = $("#img_highres_preload")[0];
    
    if (!image.complete || (typeof image.naturalWidth != "undefined" && image.naturalWidth == 0)) {
        console.log("Waiting for high-res image.");
    }
    else if (!$("#div_home").hasClass("div_home_highres")) {
        $("#div_home").addClass("div_home_highres");
        $("#img_highres_preload").remove();
    }
}
```

The checkImage function examines the image element to see whether an image has in fact been loaded. In this code example, it is a little redundant — that is, the img element has confirmed the load, so there's usually no need to check it (unless there is some reason to believe the file is being misloaded).

I might do it as shown because I also call checkImage from other places in my code, so if I have more of a programmatic response (unlike the simple version shown), I want all of that code in the same place and written just once. The checkImage function might be called when triggered by a timer or when the section displaying the intended image is about to be displayed. Perhaps something like this...

```
if (sectionName == "[whatever]" && $("#img_highres_preload").length === 1) {
    checkImage();
}
```

In this example, I look for the presence of the preload img element because I know that my previous function removes the element after it has fulfilled its purpose.

This post has a stripped-down version to illustrate the concept. As written above, it only accommodates a single known img element, so the code could be extended to call checkImage with some parameters (e.g., the name of an image or the element itself) and checkImage could look for the existence of the preload element, so that check occurs in one place. It can be fairly fancy, so I went with the simplest example for this post.

In many cases, this stripped-down version is all I need because typically I only use a high-res photo for a window background image. I either start with the display of a low-res image and switch it out as soon as the high-res file is loaded, or I have some animation that gets triggered after I confirm the presence of the high-res image.

A good case for a more generalized version is when I need a series of images loaded at the outset and don't want to start until all of them are ready. In those cases, the web page might begin with some welcome text that stays displayed until all images have been confirmed.

Answer (score -2):

Hey Guys I know this has been an older question but if you are still flickering after all this you can simply put the final version behind you background div. That flicker is seeing behind the image you currently have so if its the final image it will be smooth.