# How to prevent the flickering background image in Firefox and Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

```
<video id="movie" preload autoplay loop style="display: none;">
    <source src='example.mp4' type='video/mp4' />
</video>

<canvas id="myCanvas" style="display: none;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<div id="img" class="img" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>

<script>
    var v=document.getElementById("movie");
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var a=document.getElementById("img");
    var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
    var i;

    i=window.setInterval(function() {
        ctx.drawImage(v,0,0,90,90);

        var img_tag = new Image();
        var img = c.toDataURL();
        img_tag.onload = function() {
            a.style.backgroundImage="url("+img+")";
        }
        img_tag.src = img;
    },20);
</script>
```

I am trying to throw the current frame of the video onto the `<div id='img'>` every 20 millisecond by using javascript. I have referred to the following question:

> [How to prevent a background image flickering on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269759/how-to-prevent-a-background-image-flickering-on-change)

The questioner had the same problem as me. I have applied his solution, like the code above, but the problem still exists. Though the flickering problem doesn't appear to happen in Chrome but it still appears in Firefox and Safari, even in IE. How can I solve this problem?

P.S. The HTML must upload to the **server**. Besides, the video must come from the same server.

Comment: You cannot. That is the simplest answer. The video has no image to display before it is loaded, thus your video will ALWAYS flicker before that happens. A way around it is to use 2 players, keep track of which one is "active", load the next video in the inactive one, then just switch them.