# Flickering images when loading in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Okay so I have the following situation: I have a server which provides a Webinterface. In it, there is an image, changing constantly. However, the image flickers when I connect from another PC.

I tried fixing this issue using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269759/how-to-prevent-a-background-image-flickering-on-change) solution, but it does only work locally (e.g. when I connect to the web interface from the host PC).

The image is loaded this way:

```js
var img = new Image();
$(img).bind('load', function(event) {
    // Change background image
    element.css('background-image', url_full);
});
// Set URL of new image -> image is loaded
img.src = url;
```

Loading the image with `requestAnimationFrame()` only makes it worse and the page lags out a lot.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/369188/) is a minimal working example, however, the image doesn't appear to flicker there.

Did anybody experience this as well / have a fix for this? Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:** The flickering occurs only in Firefox and Microsoft Edge, as it seems. Chrome, Internet Explorer and Opera do not seem to have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue: In the old JS, `background-image` was used to change the image. Despite not being a very nice solution, it caused the flickering of the image.

To fix it, I replaced the original `<div>`-element (with the property `background-image` as the image) with an `<img>`-object. My JS now changes the `src`-property of this element, thus fixing the flickering.

Answer (score 0):

> please share full code. As of now I can suggest to use :

```
`var img = new Image();
$(img).bind('load', function(event) {
    // Change background image
    event.stopPropagation();//to stop bubbling
    element.css('background-image', url_full);
});`
```

> If this also doesn't work please try to unbind your load event first:

```
$(img).unbind('load');
```