# White flash/flicker on Safari when setting background-image src with intersection observer?

Tags: javascript, css, intersection-observer

I've researched quite a bit and can't solve this issue. Only appears on Safari (Mac & iOS). Works on Chrome, FF, Edge, etc.

**UPDATE: The flickering occurs in FireFox as well...**

I'm using the IntersectionObserver API along with the required polyfil to lazy load images. When they come into view, the intersection observer replaces the low resolution image set as the `background-image` and replaces it with the high resolution image stored in a data attribute on the div.

The behaviour is 'working' as the blurry initial image is set, then replaced by the high quality one but there is a white flicker or flash happening inbetween... (The background of the page is white so maybe that's what is showing through?)

After some reading: ([How to prevent a background image flickering on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269759/how-to-prevent-a-background-image-flickering-on-change)) I did fix the jumping issue by preloading the images using the `new Image()` consructor.

```
const setBackgroundImage = (e) => { 
  let image = new Image();
  image.onload = () => e.style.backgroundImage = `url(${e.dataset.bgImage})`;
  image.src = e.dataset.bgImage;
};
```

An example HTML element (PHP):

```
<div class="my-div" 
     style="background-image: url('<?= $imagePreload ?? $image; ?>');" 
     data-bg-image="<?= $image; ?>"
</div>
```

I've tried playing around with `backface-visibility: hidden` but no luck there. I'm not animating anything, just replacing the `src` on the `div` with the preloaded, full size image.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by loading the higher resolution image *before* it scrolls into view. Set the `rootMargin` option to something like `200px` when creating your `IntersectionObserver` to have the browser start loading the image 200px before it enters the viewport.