# move mouse but only on the width of the div

Tags: javascript, html

I just adapted this code to play a sequence of images when you move the mouse on the x axis. I have two questions about this code:

- I can't adapt the length to the width of the div, not to the width of the whole window.
- There are "flashes" when I move the mouse, I have the impression that it comes from the loading of the images?

Thanks for your help.

Live: https://codepen.io/nicolastilly/pen/jOBKxKK

Code:

```
var blocWidth;
var imgblock = ['https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame0.png', 
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame1.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame2.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame3.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame4.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame5.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame6.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame7.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame8.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame9.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame10.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame11.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame12.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame13.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame14.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame15.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame16.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame17.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame18.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame19.png',
                'https://assets.codepen.io/265602/frame20.png'];

function onMouseMove(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var theimg = imgblock[parseInt(x / blocWidth * imgblock.length)];
    $('.bloc1').css("background-image", "url('" + theimg + "')");
}

function onResize() {
    blocWidth = $('.bloc1').width();
}

function onResize() {
    blocWidth = $(document).width();
}

$(window).on('mousemove', onMouseMove);
$(window).resize(onResize);
onResize();
```

Comment: @Kinglish i want to move the mouse only in the `<div class="bloc1"></div>` for the length of images , not on the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for flickering, you can circumvent that by preloading the images

```
let loaded = 0 ;
imgblock.forEach(url => {
    let img=new Image();
    img.src=url;
    img.onload = onImgLoaded
})

function onImgLoaded() {
    loaded++;
    if (loaded == imgblock.length-1) console.log('all images have pre-loaded');
}
```

As for the sizing issue, you need to take into account if you're mousing over the target and accounting for the div's left value in your calculations. Get rid of both these:

```
function onResize() {
    blocWidth = $('.bloc1').width();
}

function onResize() {
    blocWidth = $(document).width();
}
```

replace with:

```
let blocStartX;
function onResize() {
    let pos = $(".bloc1")[0].getBoundingClientRect()
    console.log(pos)
    blocWidth = pos.width;
    blocStartX = pos.x 
}
```

Detect the mouseover:

```
let isOnDiv = false
$(".bloc1").mouseenter(function(){isOnDiv=true;});
$(".bloc1").mouseleave(function(){isOnDiv=false;});
```

and add this to the top of your mousemove function:

```
if (!isOnDiv) return
var x = e.pageX - blocStartX;
```

https://codepen.io/john-tyner/pen/wvJXXQZ

Comment: thank you for your response. Where do i add the preloading code ? I try to add it but it didn't work.

Comment: add it after the array `var imgblock = [...]`

Comment: also, you can put a console.log() statement in the onImgLoaded function to make sure it's getting called

Comment: I have the impression that it works, but sometimes there are still some "flashes". Thanks!
For the size of the div, your css code does not change anything. The length of the image sequence is still based on the page width, not the width of the div.

Comment: Please see revised answer and link

Comment: Also, the flickering is mitigated by preloading, but not solved, and different browsers might react differently. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269759/how-to-prevent-a-background-image-flickering-on-change/43418402

Comment: Great! Can you please mark this as the answer?