# Python to Webpage Video Server Glitch

Tags: python, html, css, opencv, websocket

I'm attempting to stream low-latency FPV video from my Raspberry Pi Zero W to my 4B that has a screen. I want the video stream in a webpage, so I created a server using the WebSockets API and the websockets package.

I created this Python script to serve images captured by a cv2 Video Capture:

```
import time
import cv2
import asyncio
import websockets
import base64


async def handle_connection(websocket, path):
    """
    Websocket connection handler
    :param websocket: Conected websocket
    :param path: Path of connected websocket
    :return: None
    """
    for frame in get_frames():
        await websocket.send(frame)


def get_frames():
    """
    Generator function that uses cv2 to stream frames to a websocket,
    yielding byte-encoded frames.
    :return: None
    """
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()  # read the camera frame
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.png', frame)
            frame = base64.b64encode(buffer)
            yield b'data:image/png;base64,' + frame


# Start video capture
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# Start the server
start_server = websockets.serve(handle_connection, "localhost", 8000)

# Do async stuff
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

As far as I know, it works as expected. The issue is in the frontend HTML, JS and CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
        function $(id){
            return document.getElementById(id)
        }

        document.onload = function(){
            test = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/");

            test.onmessage = async function (event) {
                var text = await event.data.text();
                $("body").style.backgroundImage = text;
            }
        }

        test = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/");

        test.onmessage = async function (event) {
            var text = await event.data.text();
            $("stream").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + text + "')";
            console.log("Updated FPV");
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        #stream {
            background-image: none;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center, center;
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="stream"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the server and open this HTML file it sort of works, with just one annoying issue being that it seems that every time it updates the background it makes the background white before putting in the new frame. This means that the video is full of white frames - not what I hoped for!

I tried changing the image type from JPEG to PNG but that didn't help. I had expected that when it changed the background, it would leave the previous background in place, but apparently that's not the case. I tested my code in Firefox and Safari, Safari was a little better but still pretty bad, It's also possible that the white frame is a result of a bug passing a bad frame.

Edit:
I tried adding a delay to the generator function and didn't get any fully white frames, and it still flickered when updating frames, so it's probably not a bug in the code.

Comment: This issue is solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269759/how-to-prevent-a-background-image-flickering-on-change